# Print a file saved in C #

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, printing

I'm trying to print in winform, it turns out that when I print the document, I get the blank sheet.
This is the code with which I try to print:

```
    private PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
    private string stringToPrint;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadPrint();
        printDocument1.Print();
    }

    private void ReadPrint()
    {
        string docName = "ejemplo.pdf";
        string docPath = @"C:\dir1\";
        printDocument1.DocumentName = docName;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(docPath + docName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            stringToPrint = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int charactersOnPage = 0;
        int linesPerPage = 0;


        e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint, this.Font,
            e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
            out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);


        e.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, this.Font, Brushes.Black,
            e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);


        stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage);

        e.HasMorePages = (stringToPrint.Length > 0);
    }

    private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LeerArchivo();
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
```

I would like to know if there is a way to correct it or some other way to print the file?Or some example code?
regards

In stringToPrint:
[image]

Comment: You're trying to load PDF data (which is binary) into a string. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, Yes, a pdf file, then, what would be done for these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vb.net has a PrintForm method but C# does not have inbuilt method for printing a Windows Form.

To print a windows form at runtime in C#.net. The base concept involves the capture of  the screen image of a Form in jpeg format during runtime and printing the same on a event like Print button click.

[print](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/srajlaxmi/printing-windows-form-in-C-Sharp-net/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the stringToPrint is not empty or null ? I'm using the same thing and it works perfectly. You should try to add a print PrintPreviewDialog in case you want to check if the document to be print is not blank. Check your variables first.

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("SomeString", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(580, 510));

e.Graphics.DrawString("SomeString1", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(700, 510));
```

for the parameter new Point() it is where your text appears via x and y coordinates.

Comment: Edit the question, stringToPrint has data according to the photo, copy the code looking in google. The difference that FileAccess.Read added to it, since I got an error that I did not have permission to access the route